# Trying to find CategoryID for News on YouTube V3 API

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have an automated upload process which posts videos to YouTube using the V3 Upload api. I was able to use the APIExplorer to get a list of available category IDs but I am not able to find News anymore. I was previously able to post videos to this category using the v2 API and specifying a category URL in the XML body.

In the Youtube v3 API, you have to give a categoryID instead. I've been having to use 22 (People & Blogs), for my uploads... but News is really more appropriate. Does anyone know what the category ID for News is or where I could find a more comprehensive list?

Answer (score -1):

The category id for news and politics is 25.